# Eigenvalues of random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I am studying random matrix and stuck by a problem. Is there any way that I can calculate or describe eigenvalues of random matrix? My first attempt was as follows:

Let $A$ be random matrix s.t. $A=(a_{ij})$ and $a_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Let $\lambda$ be eigenvalue of random matrix A and let $x$ be eigenvector of $A$. As 
\begin{equation}
Ax=\lambda x
\end{equation}
we can expand this as
\begin{equation}
a_{i1}x_{1}+\cdots+a_{in}x_{n}=\lambda x_{i}
\end{equation}
And IF WE ALLOW $x_{i}$ to be scalars not depending on random variables $a_{ij}$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(a_{i1}x_{1}+\cdots+a_{in}x_{n})&=\mathbb{E}(\lambda x_{i})\\
\mathbb{E}(a_{i1})x_{1}+\cdots+ \mathbb{E}(a_{in})x_{1}&=\mathbb{E}(\lambda)x_{i}\\
0&=\mathbb{E}(\lambda)x_{i}
\end{align}
Thus, $\mathbb{E}(\lambda)=0$(assuming $x_{i}\neq0$)
And by same method, we can show variance of $\lambda$ to be $\mathbb{V}(\lambda)=n\sigma^{2}$.

I think there is a serious problem in that I assumed $x_{i}$s to be scalar.

1. Is there any way to solve this problem?
2. Is there any depiction or theorem about eigenvalues of a random matrix defined as I defined?

Comment: Your problem is not well-posed. $A$ has $n$ random eigenvalues. You need to specify a method for picking one of them before talking about its expected value.

Comment: [Wigner's Semicircle Law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @user1551 What can be said about maximum eigenvalue of $A$??

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thx very much!

Comment: $\mathbb C$ is not an ordered field. There is no such thing as a "maximum" eigenvalue. If you are talking about the spectral radius, I don't know the answer, but I'd bet that this has been studied in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix model you described is called the **real Ginibre ensemble**, provided that all of your $a_{i,j}$'s are i.i.d. The result is not standard, which can be found from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.2020.pdf).